# Adjusting the height of a Div Automatically for PNPJS ListView in a SPFX Webpart

Tags: css, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am working with a SPFX WebPart that has a pnpjs listview.
The list view items amount can change dynamically so the number of rows will also change.
And i want the height to adjust to the items of the list and dont show a scroll bar.
So far i have not been able to do this.

Here is my css and my tsx code.

```
.webPart {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  color: "[theme:bodyText, default: #323130]";
  color: var(--bodyText);
  width: 100%;
}

.textfield {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.WPTQGMainDiv {
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
  color: "[theme:bodyText, default: #323130]";
  color: var(--bodyText);
  background-color: yellow;
  height: auto;
}

.WPTQGDivListView {
  padding: 0px;
}

.WPTQGDocumentListView {
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: max-content;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```
     <section className={`${styles.webPart} `}>
        <div className={styles.WPTQGMainDiv} >
          <h2 className={styles.WPTitle}>{escape(description)}</h2>

          <input className={styles.textfield} type="hidden" ref={(input) => (this.searchInput = input)} width={255} />
          <div className={styles.divInline}>
            <table >
              <tr>
                <td >
                  <input id='countryCodeInput' className={styles.textfield} type="text" value={this.state.ctycode} ref={(countryCodeInput) => (this.countryCodeInput = countryCodeInput)} onChange={this.handleInputChange('ctycode')} placeholder='Country Code' />
                </td>
                <td >
                  <input id='countryNameInput' className={styles.textfield} type="text" value={this.state.ctyName} ref={(countryNameInput) => (this.countryNameInput = countryNameInput)} onChange={this.handleInputChange('ctyName')} placeholder='Country Name' />
                </td>
                <td >
                  <input id='regionInput' className={styles.textfield} type="text" value={this.state.region} ref={(regionInput) => (this.regionInput = regionInput)} onChange={this.handleInputChange('region')} placeholder='Region' />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

          <ListView items={this.state.resultDocs}
            className={styles.WPTQGDocumentListView}
            iconFieldName="AppPath"
            viewFields={viewFieldsISPDocuments}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}
            compact={true}
            stickyHeader={true}
          />
        </div>
      </section>
```

Any one has any idea on how i can make this work?

i have tried myltiple css configurations but i cannot get it to work